# Find torsion classes using flat bundles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, cohomology, vector-bundles, derham-cohomology

My question refers to a discussion from  [this older thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2073846/neron-severi-group-h1-1x-mathbbz) on Neron-Severi group of a Kähler manifold. In the comments below Ted Shifrin's answer there arose a discussion when the map $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ induced by the canonical inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{C}$ may be not injective. As Ted pointed out the main reason that prevents this map being injective is the presence torsion in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$.

Then he continues: "...From the line bundle side, you can see this with flat bundles (whose curvature forms vanish, and so the de Rham representative is the zero form)."

Unfortunately I not understand how his example & argument for line bundles by considering to flat bundles work. Definitely, as the curvature forms of flat bundles vanish, their de Rham representative in $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ is zero. That's fine.

Why does it provide an example for torsion elements in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$? Does their de Rham representative not already vanish in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ as the curvature is zero? But then it not provide an example for a torsion element.

Does anybody understand what Ted had by the quoted remark in mind? I tried to ask but probably that was quite obvious point and I'm just too fool to see it.

Comment: The de Rham representative is a differential form so does not give an element of  $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Lefschetz theorem tells you that any torsion class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is the first Chern class of a line bundle, then necessarily flat. Like the thread you quote, the question would be more appropriate in MSE.

Comment: @abx:The Lefschetz theorem (at least which I know) says that the first Chern map $c_1: H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ (that associating to a holomorphic line bundle its Chern class $c_1$) induces isomorphism $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)/ker(c_1) \cong H^{(1,1)}(X,\mathbb{Z})$, where the right object is given by $H^{(1,1)}(X,\mathbb{Z})=Im(H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})) \cap H^{1,1}(X)$. As $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X^*)$ classifies holom line bundles $c_1$ associates as you said first Chern classes to line bundles. (reference: D. Huybrecht's Complex Geometry page 133).

Comment: One point I not understand: you say that Lefschetz theorem tells that any torsion class $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ that is the first class of a line bundle (in other words is contained in the image of $c_1$,right?), is neccessary flat, right? What I don't understand is that does the asumption imply that a torsion element of $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ which is contained in the image of $c_1$, is already $0$? By def $im(C_1)=H^{(1,1)}(X,\mathbb{Z})=Im(H^2(X, \mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})) \cap H^{1,1}(X)$ says that image of $c_1$ has no torsion. Or do I misunderstand your point?

Comment: ps: yes, you are right that this question has indeed a MSE-level. I have tried to ask it to weeks ago https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519053/understand-torsion-using-flat-bundles but unfortunately it doesn't get much attention.

Comment: No, the image of $c_1$ can have torsion — in fact, let me repeat that any torsion class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is $c_1(L)$ for some $L$ — just use the exponential exact sequence.

Comment: @abx: Could you give reference for the version of Lefschetz thm you mentioned above that states that all torison classes are hit by certain line bundles via $c_1$? I not see now I can derive it instantly from that one on page 133 from Huybrecht's book. Ok and so the conclusion that these preimages of torsion classes must be flat follows simply by definition as $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ kills torsion...

Comment: This follows from the exact sequence $H^1(X,\mathscr{O}_X^*)\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^2(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ that you'll find in any book on complex geometry, e.g. Griffiths-Harris.

Comment: sorry for digging out this topic but as I recently was reading your comments on statement confuses me: you say "Lefschetz theorem tells you that any torsion class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is the first Chern class of a line bundle, then necessarily flat." I agree with you that using exponential sequence we conclude that any torion class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ has a primage by Chern map $c_1$. That's just the exactness. But you say also that any torsion class comes from a *flat* line bundle.

Comment: Why? A flat bundle $L$ is characterized by vanishing curvature $\Omega_L=0$. Of course we can project the curvature to it's class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$ and since it's obviously zero in $H^2(X,\mathbb{C})$, then it's a torsion. That's clear. But why we can conclude also in other direction? That is the that a line bundle that is associated by $c_1$ to a torsion class, is flat?